# Looking for wordpress like visual editor

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, editor, visual-editor

Does anyone know of a script like the wordpress like visual editor!

So basically I want to give users the option to just write and adjust the font color size ... within a visual editor but also give them the option to see how it looks in the sourcecode!

**Thanks for your answers**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try out http://ckeditor.com

1.CKEditor is a text editor to be used inside web pages. It's a WYSIWYG editor, which means that the text being edited on it looks as similar as possible to the results users have when publishing it. It brings to the web common editing features found on desktop editing applications like Microsoft Word and OpenOffice.

2.Because CKEditor is licensed under flexible Open Source and commercial licenses, you'll be able to integrate and use it inside any kind of application. This is the ideal editor for developers, created to provide easy and powerful solutions to their users.

Comment: do you know something like wordpress `visual composer page builder` ?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).

> TinyMCE is a platform independent web based Javascript HTML WYSIWYG
>   editor control released as Open Source under LGPL by Moxiecode Systems
>   AB.
>
> TinyMCE has the ability to convert HTML TEXTAREA fields or other HTML
>   elements to editor instances. TinyMCE is very easy to integrate into
>   other Content Management Systems.

You can also customize it to the functionality you need.